# cross joining two tables

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this, lets call this table `B`.

```
id    boardid    schoolid     subject     cnt1   cnt2  cnt3 ....
=================================================================
1       20         21           f     
2       20         21           r
3       20         21           w
4       20         21           m
5       20         30           r
6       20         30           w
7       20         30           m
```

Suppose the counts are just integers. Notice that there is no `subject = f` for `schoolid = 30`. Similarly, for most schools, some `subject` dosnt exist. You might have a `schoolid` that has just `r, w` or some that are just `r, m, f`..

So what I want to do is have 4 consistent rows for each school, and the row that dosnt exist I want dummy values. I thought about creating a secondary table

```
drop table #A
Select * into #A FROM 
(
select [subject_s] = 'r', orderNo = 1
union all
select [subject_s] = 'w', orderNo = 2
union all
select [subject_s] = 'm', orderNo = 3
union all
select [subject_s] = 'f', orderNo = 4
) z
```

and doing some joins on them, but I've gotten NO where. I've tried inner join, left outer, cross join, everything. I've even tried to make cartesian product. I think my cartesian product messes up because I have `orderno` in there so it makes 16 rows per row in the main table. Actually typing this out, I realize if I remove the `orderno`, apply the cartesian product and then add orderno in later, it might work but I am interested to see what you guys can come up with. I am stumped.

End result

```
id    boardid    schoolid     subject     cnt1   cnt2  cnt3 ....
=================================================================
1       20         21           r     
2       20         21           w
3       20         21           m
4       20         21           f
5       20         30           r
6       20         30           w
7       20         30           m
7       20         30           f
```

Comment: Do you have a table with all subjects? How can you determine all subjects that need to appear in each schoolid?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?, and why does the last row of your end result has an `id` of 7?

Comment: Typo, id is a autogenerated number. And I have created a temp table will all my subjects ( there are only four)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT S.boardid, S.schoolid, A.[subject], B.cnt1, B.cnt2, B.cnt3
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT boardid, schoolid FROM YourTable) S
CROSS JOIN #A A
LEFT JOIN YourTable B
    ON B.boardid = S.boardid AND  B.schoolid = S.schoolid 
    AND A.[subject] = B.[subject]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know which RDBMS you are using I tried the following with `sqlite` and a simpler table:

```
sqlite> create table schools (name varchar, subject varchar, teacher varchar);

sqlite> select * from schools;
School1|Maths|Mr Smith
School2|English|Jack
School3|English|Jimmy
School3|Maths|Jane
School4|Computer Science|Bob

sqlite> select
            schoolnames.name, 
            subjects.subject, 
            ifnull(teachers.teacher, "Unknown") 
        from (select distinct name from schools) schoolnames
        join (select distinct subject from schools) subjects
        left join schools teachers
           on schoolnames.name = teachers.name
              and subjects.subject = teachers.subject;

School1|Maths|Mr Smith
School1|English|Unknown
School1|Computer Science|Unknown

School2|Maths|Unknown
School2|English|Jack
School2|Computer Science|Unknown

School3|Maths|Jane
School3|English|Jimmy
School3|Computer Science|Unknown

School4|Maths|Unknown
School4|English|Unknown
School4|Computer Science|Bob
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use:

```
SELECT 
    boardid, schoolid, dist_subject, id, cnt1, ...
FROM
    (SELECT 
        boardid, schoolid, dist_subject
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            DISTINCT subject AS dist_subject 
        FROM b ) s full outer join
        (SELECT 
            boardid, schoolid 
        FROM b 
        GROUP BY 
            boardid, schoolid   ) g ) sg LEFT OUTER JOIN
    b ON 
    sg.boardID = b.boardID AND
    sg.schoolid = b.schoolID
    sg.dist_subject = b.subject
```

Comment: Never use implioct joins. They are a SQl antipattern.  Use a cross join instead, then the person maintaining the script willknow it wasn't an accidental cross join but an intended one.